# distortion on core audio's newTimePitch audio unit

Tags: core-audio

I am attempting to incorporate the newTimePitch audio unit in my iOS app. I have constructed an AUGraph with a filePlayer Unit -> subType_NewTimePitch Unit -> remoteIO Unit.  I have found that the output of newTimePitch unit is distorted.  This distortion is persistent even at the default rate (1.0) and pitch (0) parameters.

I have performed a simple test for confirmation: on my auGraph, I swapped the subType_NewTimePitch for subType_Varispeed, keeping all other parameters the same, and the distortion disappears.  I also tried to place a mixer unit upstream of the newTimePitch in order to reduce the input gain to the newTimePitch unit.  Of course, this reduced the overall output of the unit but did nothing to ameliorate the distortion.  I have found that, although the distortion is not particularly noticeable in the iOS Simulator, it is definitely present on an actual device (iPad2).

I would be very interested in others' experience and/or solutions.

Comment: What kind of distortion are you detecting?

Answer (score 0):

I also found this, just went back to the old time pitch unit.

Comment: I can best describe the distortion of the NewTimePitch audio unit has having a metallic/robotic quality (esp. on vocals).  This distortion becomes more obvious as one changes the rate parameter but, as I mentioned, is present at the default values as well.  I am interested in comparing the performance of the "old" timePitch audio unit - please let me know where I can find it.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: dorada,  you mention going back to the "old" time pitch unit.  I have tried to use subType_TimePitch but autocomplete simply refers to subType_NewTimePitch instead...

Answer (score 0):

Greg, I've also use newTimePitch audio unit in my app. I don't found any distortion or noise on simulator. What about device: unfortunately I have no sound at all with NewTimePitch node ( [iOS Sounds with AudioUnit works on simulator, not on real device iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16257092/ios-sounds-with-audiounit-works-on-simulator-not-on-real-device-ipad) ). If I use AUConverter node instead of NewTimePitch the sound is playing good. I've also tried Varispeed, but with no success too. Do you know the possible reason of missing the sound on iPad?

I have several suggestions for your issue:
1) your NewTimePitch is the first node in your graph? And input render callback is associated with it? If yes, then did you try to add for example Mixer node as the first node and NewTimePitch after it? It can make sense if issue is related to stream format.

2) did you try to add AUConverter node between NewTimePitch node and remoteIO node? It can make sense if issue is related to stream format.

3) did you try to launch compiled app on device not from XCode? It can make sense if you have logs in render callback (big number of log information cause no sound at all or bad sound).

Comment: Sorry Ted, I am not sure why your iOS app using NewTimePitch or Varispeed does not work on the device. My app does not use a render callback and the NewTimePitch unit is not the first node on the auGraph.  I will attempt to integrate an AUConverter node and see what happens...

Answer (score 0):

There is a BypassEffect property that can be set on the NewTimePitch converter Audio Unit if you don't want it to affect the sound at the default pitch and rate (no change).

I've only tested this on an iOS 6 device, but both NewTimePitch and the bypass appears to work there.

Comment: hotpaw2, thanks for the advice on the bypass property of the NewTimePitch Unit; unfortunately, I would like to actually use its effects. I just mention that the distortion is present default values. You also describe not having any problems with the NewTimePitch on your iOS 6 device.  If possible, would you elaborate on your code setup for use of the unit (e.g. auGraph, use of callback, etc) and some parameter ranges?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: I used an AU graph to attach the NewTimePitch AU directly to RemoteIO bus 0 (speaker), and fed it samples from a buffer callback (my own mixer code).

Comment: I just finished re-writing the code integrating the NewTimePitch unit using a render callback.  At this point the distortion remains on the device (confirmed by swapping a subType_Varispeed for subType_NewTimePitch).  I may have forgotten to mention my device - iPad 2 running iOS 6.1.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue using a render callback -> Mixer unit -> NewTimePitch unit -> Mixer unit -> RemoteIO unit. Two workarounds I found:

1) Use the Varispeed unit and set the kNewTimePitchParam_Pitch property on it (undocumented, but works).

2) Use a AUFilePlayer instead of a render callback.

Result: Player unit -> NewTimePitch unit -> Mixer unit -> RemoteIO unit

Note on workaround 2: I needed to get the kAudioUnitProperty_StreamFormat from the pitch unit and set player unit's output format to it, and mixer unit's input format to it.